# FIGMA and Sketch is increasing the filesize of images

Tags: sketch-app, figma

I encountered a very interesting phenomenon. I hope someone here can explain it to me. When I am importing an image with 936 KB of file size and then immediately export that same image (without editing anything) then the image suddenly has 2.5 MB. Can someone explain this behavior to me? Is this a bug? What is happening here?

Interestingly the same happens in Sketch too.

Here is a video showing this: https://youtu.be/ODo2dOOC4-g

Comment: Added metadata, different compression settings.

Answer (score 0):

The image gets re-rendered so the encoded compressed image data would be completely different if you export it. If you download the original image from the Inspect panel in Figma, however, you will get the same image which isn't re-rendered and compressed differently.

[image: Figma Inspect panel download original]